# How to make an average of all the windows containing a frame?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following situation. I have an array of size (3, 128, n) (where n is large). (This array represents a picture). I have a superresolution deep learning model that takes as input a (3, 128, 128) picture and gives it back in better quality. I want to use apply my model to the whole picture.

### My existing solution

My first solution to this problem is to split my array into array of size (3, 128, 128). I then have a list of square images, and I can apply my model to each of this square and then concatenate all the results to get a new (3, 128, n) image. The problem with this method is that the model does not perform as well on the edges of the image.

### My desired solution

To get around this problem, I have thought of an alternative solution. Instead of considering non overlapping square images, I can consider all square images that can be extracted from my original image. I can pass all those images to my model. Then to reconstruct a point of coordinates (a, b, c), I will consider all reconstructed square pictures that contains c, and take an average of them. I want this average to give more weight to the square where c is near the center.
To be more specific :

- I start with a 3*128*n array (let's call it A). I pad on the left and on the right which gives me a new array (let's call it A_pad) of size `3*128*(n+2*127)`
- For i in range(0,n+127), let `A_i = A_pad[:, :, i:i+128]`, `A_i` is of size (3*128*128) and can be fed to my model which creates a new array `B_i` of the same size.
- Now I want a new array `B` of the same size than A that is defined like this :  For each (x, y , z), `B[x, y, z]` is the mean of the 128 `B_i[x, y, z+127-i]` such that z <= i < z+128 with the weight `1 + min(z + 127 -i, i-z)`. That corresponds to taking the mean of all the windows that contains z with a weight proportional to the distance to the closest edge.

My question is based on the computation of B. Given what I've described, I could write multiple `for` loops that would yield the correct results, but I'm afraid it would be slow. I'm looking for a solution using numpy that is as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example implementation that follows the steps you outlined in the section "My desired solution". It makes extensive use of [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) which at first glance might not seem obvious at all; I added detailed comments to each usage for clarification. Also note that in your description you use `z` to denote the column position within images while in comments I use the term `n-position` in order to comply with the shape specification via `n`.

Regarding efficiency it's not obvious whether this is a winner or not. Computation happens all in numpy but the expression `sliding_128 * weights` builds a large array (128x the size of the original image) before reducing it along the frame dimension. This definitely comes at its cost, memory might even be an issue. A loop might come in handy at this position.

Lines which contain a comment prefixed with `# [TEST]` were added for testing purposes. Concretely this means we're overwriting the weights for the final sum of frames with `1 / 128` in order to eventually recover the original image (since no ML model transformation is applied either).

```
import numpy as np

n = 640  # For example.
image = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(3, 128, n))
print('image.shape: ', image.shape)  # (3, 128, 640)

padded = np.pad(image, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (127, 127)), mode='edge')
print('padded.shape: ', padded.shape)  # (3, 128, 894)

sliding = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    padded,
    # Frames stored along first dimension; sliding across last dimension of `padded`.
    shape=(padded.shape[-1]-128+1, 3, 128, 128),
    # First dimension: Moving one frame ahead -> move across last dimension of `padded`.
    # Remaining three dimensions: Move as within `padded`.
    strides=(padded.strides[-1:] + padded.strides)
)
print('sliding.shape: ', sliding.shape)  # (767, 3, 128, 128)

# Now at this part we would feed the frames `sliding` to the ML model,
# where the first dimension is the batch size.
# Assume the output is assigned to `sliding` again.
# Since we're not using an ML model here, we create a copy instead
# in order to update the strides of `sliding` with it's actual shape (as defined above).
sliding = sliding.copy()

sliding_128 = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
    # Reverse last dimension since we want the last column from the first frame.
    # Need to copy again because `[::-1]` creates a view with negative stride,
    # but we want actual reversal to work with the strides below.
    # (There's perhaps a smart way of adjusting the strides below in order to not make a copy here.)
    sliding[:, :, :, ::-1].copy(),
    # Second dimension corresponds to the 128 consecutive frames.
    # Previous last dimension is dropped since we're selecting the
    # column that corresponds to the current n-position.
    shape=(128, n, 3, 128),
    # First dimension (frame position): Move one frame and one column ahead
    #     (actually want to move one column less in `sliding` but since we reverted order of columns
    #      we need to move one ahead now) -> move across first dimension of `sliding` + last dimension of `sliding`.
    # Second dimension (n-position): Moving one frame ahead -> move across first dimension of `sliding`.
    # Remaining two dimensions: Move within frames (channel and row dimensions).
    strides=((sliding.strides[0] + sliding.strides[-1],) + sliding.strides[:1] + sliding.strides[1:3])
)
print('sliding_128.shape: ', sliding_128.shape)  # (128, 640, 3, 128)

# Weights are independent of the n-position -> we can precompute.
weights = 1 + np.concatenate([np.arange(64), np.arange(64)[::-1]])
weights = np.ones(shape=128)  # [TEST] Assign weights for testing -> want to obtain the original image back.
weights = weights.astype(float) / weights.sum()  # Normalize?
weights = weights[:, None, None, None]  # Prepare for broadcasting.

weighted_image = np.moveaxis(np.sum(sliding_128 * weights, axis=0), 0, 2)
print('weighted_image.shape: ', weighted_image.shape)  # (3, 128, 640)

assert np.array_equal(image, weighted_image.astype(int))  # [TEST]
```

Comment: This is quite a complete and well explained answer. Thank you very much. I will try this in the upcoming days and accept your answer if it works :)

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much. I just modified 2 things during my usage. I did a different padding based on my knowledge of the data and to apply my models and create sliding I did `sliding = np.stack([predict_method(array[:, :, i:i+sz])
                        for i in tqdm(range(n+sz-1))])` where predict_method calls my deep learning models and return the new array.